# How to populate a pandas column by conditional lookup of values in other Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to populate a pandas column by looking up values in other DataFrames with the lookup DataFrame and column being decided by the contents of a column in the source data frame.

Here is an example using 3 DataFrames:

source_df:

| Type | Code | Column_x | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 123456 | blah |  |
|  |  | blah | Code345 |
| CI | Name_of_thing1 | blah2 |  |
| CC | 65874 | blah blah |  |
| ID | 987654 | blah |  |

Lookup1:

| ID | CI | col3 | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Name_of_thing1 | blah | Description of thing 1 |
| 987654 | Name_of_other_1 | blah | Description of other thing |

Lookup2:

| CC | BU | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 65874 | finance | Description blah blah |
| pop45 | sales | Another Description |

If possible I would like to avoid iterating through the rows of the source DF with a combination of for loops and if statements but using for loops and if statements this is what I'm trying to achieve (example code below intended as a type of pseudo code rather than 100% correct python code):

```
for row in source_df:
   if source_df['Type'] == 'ID':
      source_df['col_new'] = Lookup1[source_df.loc['row']['Code'] == Lookup1['ID']]['description']

   else if source_df['Type'] == 'CI':
      source_df['col_new'] = Lookup1[source_df.loc['row']['Code'] == Lookup1['CI']]['description']  

   else if source_df['Type'] == 'CC':
      source_df['col_new'] = Lookup2[source_df.loc['row']['Code'] == Lookup2['CC']]['description']  

   else:
      source_df['col_new'] = source_df.loc['row']['Code2']
```

Is it possible to achieve the above without iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) first and then left join by `source_df`, if necessary replace non matched values use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.concat([Lookup1.melt('description', var_name='Type', value_name='Code'), 
                Lookup2.melt('description', var_name='Type', value_name='Code')])
print (df)
                  description  Type             Code
0      Description of thing 1    ID           123456
1  Description of other thing    ID           987654
2      Description of thing 1    CI   Name_of_thing1
3  Description of other thing    CI  Name_of_other_1
4      Description of thing 1  col3             blah
5  Description of other thing  col3             blah
0       Description blah blah    CC            65874
1         Another Description    CC            pop45
2       Description blah blah    BU          finance
3         Another Description    BU            sales

df = source_df.merge(df, how='left', on=['Type','Code'])

df['description'] = df['description'].fillna(df['Description'])
print (df)
  Type            Code   Column_x Description                 description
0   ID          123456       blah      qwaszx      Description of thing 1
1  nan             nan       blah     Code345                         NaN
2   CI  Name_of_thing1      blah2      abc123      Description of thing 1
3   CC           65874  blah blah      aaaeft       Description blah blah
4   ID          987654       blah      ght567  Description of other thing
```

Comment: After the first melt step I can see the description column in the df is populated but after the merge step the description column in df is full of NaN's

Comment: @fr0do007 - hmm, it means there is no match between `df['Type'], df['Code']` with `source_df` - some data related problem.